# Shortest way to generate 20 random numbers with specific range

Tags: php

I need to generate an array containing 20 random numbers between 1 and 200. Is there a shorter/cleaner code I can use?

```
<?php 
$x= array (rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200),rand(1,200));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($x); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: A `for` would be cleaner, https://3v4l.org/7a2GV.

Comment: You can use `for loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
  $random_num = rand(1,200);
  array_push($arr, $random_num);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

No loops needed.
Use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to create all numbers between 1-200, [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it and grab the first 20 items in the array with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$range = range(1,200);
shuffle($range);
$random = array_slice($range,0,20);
var_dump($random);
```

https://3v4l.org/fI9WZ